# Organizing packages for use in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-module

I want to access all modules no matter what my cwd is. Is there any way to access all my modules without adding `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH=`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My simplest answer is to create an example.pth inside the lib/site-packages and add any working directory that you want there.